# MySQL: List of fields where search string was found?

Tags: mysql, case

When I search several fields with MySQL `LIKE`, is there a way to know in which field(s) the string was found?

`SELECT * FROM DB WHERE title like "%search%" OR description LIKE "%search%" or tags LIKE "%search%`

I know of `CASE` `WHEN`:

`SELECT *,CASE
  WHEN title like "%search%" THEN 'title'
  [...]
  END AS found_in
WHERE [...]`

But ultimately I'd like a comma separated list of fields if the string was found in several fields.

Is this possible?

Edit to clarify:

I'd like my field `found_in' to be "title, description" when the search term is found in title & description.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way would be a series of UNIONed queries, one for each field. each returning the name of the field it is found in, then using that as a sub query and doing a GROUP_CONCAT on the result:-

```
SELECT  id,
        title,
        description,
        tags,
        GROUP_CONCAT(field_found)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'title' AS field_found, 
            id, 
            title,
            description,
            tags
    FROM DB 
    WHERE title like "%search%"
    UNION
    SELECT 'description' AS field_found, 
            id, 
            title,
            description,
            tags
    FROM DB 
    WHERE description LIKE "%search%"
    UNION
    SELECT 'tags' AS field_found, 
            id, 
            title,
            description,
            tags
    FROM DB 
    WHERE tags LIKE "%search%
) sub0
GROUP BY id,
        title,
        description,
        tags
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps!

Answer (score 0):

## Try this,

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN (title + description) like '%search%' THEN title +', ' + description
       [...]
       END AS found_in
  FROM [...]
 WHERE [...]
```